# Selenium locating element by image source

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to click on an element using selenium webdriver version 2.39, eclipse-kepler, IE11.

I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to find element with xpath ==
>   //img[@src='images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png'] (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Other things that give me the same error are:

> ```
> (By.xpath("//div[contains(@src,'images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png')]"));
>
>
> (By.xpath("//div[(@src,'images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png')]"));
>
>
> (By,xpath("//img[contains(@src,'images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png')]"));
> ```

Comment: Could u show me your html <div> tag that contains <img> tag?

Comment: I am working with Ayushi on the same thing. The div doesn't actually contain the <img> tag. The div highlighted by the internet explorer is - < DIV tabIndex=0 style="OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: hand; HEIGHT: 22px;
WIDTH: 60px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 10px; FILTER:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=../images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png,
sizingMethod=scale); TOP: 5px"></DIV>

Comment: You won't be able to find that element using `src` as it is not a direct attribute.

Comment: Is there any way of finding this element?

Comment: Was this issue ever solved? I have come across the same issue with another website.

Comment: this looks more like a timing issue. maybe wait some time after the page load, or after hovering the button?

Comment: Please provide HTML

Answer (score 2):

Here try using CSS Selector:

```
WebElement tempImg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src='images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@src,'images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png')]"));
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of the previous answer.

Comment: ```"*"``` please find the difference

Comment: Please provide some explanation and how it is different than other answer.

Comment: above mentioned ,as he has tried with ```//div``` & ```//img``` by using ```//*``` it will select all the tag that contains ```@src,'images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png'```

Comment: @NitishKumar - I highly recommend editing that bit of information into your answer. It's always helpful to future readers to have a little descriptive text for what your answer is proposing, in addition to just the code.

Comment: @BradLarson please guide me